# Angular simple nf show not showing

Tags: angular, ng-show

So I have a simple code but when I run, it does not hide either div I couldn't find code as simple as this on here and I am just starting angular. isnurse does return "true"

```
<div *ngIf="user">
<img src="assets/logo.png">

<h1>Hello {{user.firstName}}, {{user.isnurse}}</h1>
<a href="/api/auth/signout">Signout</a>

<div ng-show="user.isnurse == true">
    <h1>DO NURSE THINGS</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div ng-show="user.isnurse == false">
    <h1>DO PATIENT THINGS</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `*ngIf` instead of `ng-show`

> [From docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif)
>   Hiding an element is quite different from removing an element with
>   `NgIf`.
>
> *When you hide an element, that element and all of its descendants
>   remain in the DOM. All components for those elements stay in memory
>   and Angular may continue to check for changes. You could be holding
>   onto considerable computing resources and degrading performance, for
>   something the user can't see.*

Unlike the hidden property, Angular's `*ngIf` directive is not subject to style specificity constraints.  It's always safe to use regardless of your stylesheet.   However, it's worth noting that it's not functionally equivalent.  Rather than toggling the display property, it works by adding and removing template elements from the DOM
**TL:DR** 
`ngIf` is a structural directive, it creates/destroys content inside the DOM. whereas binding to the `hidden` property just hides/shows the content with css, i.e. adding/removing `display:none` to the element's style.

```
  <div *ngIf="user">
    <img src="assets/logo.png">

    <h1>Hello {{user.firstName}}, {{user.isnurse}}</h1>
    <a href="/api/auth/signout">Signout</a>

    <div *ngIf="user.isnurse">
        <h1>DO NURSE THINGS</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div  *ngIf="!user.isnurse">
        <h1>DO PATIENT THINGS</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular >= 2, use [hidden]

```
<div [hidden]="!user.isnurse">
    <h1>DO NURSE THINGS</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div [hidden]="user.isnurse">
    <h1>DO PATIENT THINGS</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In angular 2 there is hidden method for hiding component.
>
> "ng-show", "ng-hide" ar angularjs directive.

```
<div *ngIf="user">
<img src="assets/logo.png">

<h1>Hello {{user.firstName}}, {{user.isnurse}}</h1>
<a href="/api/auth/signout">Signout</a>

<div [hidden]="!user.isnurse">
    <h1>DO NURSE THINGS</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div [hidden]="user.isnurse">
    <h1>DO PATIENT THINGS</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles']">List Articles</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/articles/create']">Create Article</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```